# Infinity of a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and infinite dimensional algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a field, an infinite dimensional algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Every proper subring of $R$ is finite. We consider $$T = \{ n \in \mathbb{N}: \exists x \in R \text{ such that } x^{p^n} = x, \text{ but } x^{p^m} \neq x \text{ for every } 1 \leq m <n \}.$$ In a certain proof of a theorem, it is assured (without proof) that $T$ is infinite and contains a prime $q$, but i don't see exactly why would that be true. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: The algebraic closure of the $p$-element field is the union of fixed points of powers of the Frobenius endomorphism, and each power has only finitely many fixed points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fix an algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$ and an embedding $R \subset \bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$.

**The set $T$ is infinite:**

Given some $N > 0$, we will find an $\alpha \in R$ and $n \geq N$ such that $\alpha^{p^n} = \alpha$ but $\alpha^{p^m} \neq \alpha$ whenever $m < n$.

This is the case when $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is a primitive element for $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_p$, so it suffices to show that $\mathbb{F}_{p^n} \subset R$ for some $n \geq N$ - but if this were not the case $R$ would be finite since it would be contained in the compositum of $\mathbb{F}_p$, ..., $\mathbb{F}_{p^{N-1}}$.

**$T$ contains a prime $q$**

Notice that $R$ contains some proper finite extension $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_p$. This has cyclic galois group so by the fundemental theorem of Galois theory contains $\mathbb{F}_{p^q}$ for each prime $q \vert n$.

Then a primitive element for $\mathbb{F}_{p^q}/\mathbb{F}_p$ satisfies the condition for $q$ to be contained in $T$.